# C++ instantiation question

Tags: c++

Want to verify that my understanding of how this works.
Have a C++ Class with one public instance variable:

```
char* character_encoding;
```

and whose only constructor is defined as:

```
TF_StringList(const char* encoding = "cp_1252");
```

when I use this class in either C++/CLI or C++, the first thing I do is declare a pointer to an object of this class:

```
const TF_StringList * categories;
```

Then later I instantiate it:

```
categories = new TF_StringList();
```

this gives me a pointer to an object of type TF_StringList whose variable character_encoding is set to "cp_1252";
So, is all that logic valid?

Jim

Comment: Why is it necessary to pollute this question with the dubious prefix "unmanaged". perhaps im wrong, but im pretty sure that Stroustrup never wrote a book "The Design and Evolution of unmanaged C++".

Comment: True, my apologies to our ancestors

Comment: There is no way for us to know without having the source code for the constructor. By the way: management has nothing to do with this, so I'd appreciate if you took back your snappy comments, I am one of the few millions working with (normal) C++ :)

Comment: Not meant to be snappy, merely in the MS world I find myself dragged into some confusion does exist.

Comment: @Chris Becke, @Matthieu M.: I've removed "unmanaged" and changed "Managed C++" to the more correct "C++/CLI". Happy now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one problem i see, is that your constructor takes a const char*, but you're storing it in a char*.  That's going to cause the compiler to complain unless you cast away the constness.  (Alternatively, is there any reason not to make your field a const char* ?  i don't see you needing to edit the chars of the name...)

Comment: Clarification: I did not write the TF_StringList class, it is a 3rd party class for which I only have the header. So (1) I have no idea what is going on in the constructor and (2) can't change the modifiers on character_encoding. How does that effect your answers?

Comment: Well, we can't guarantee that what you passed the constructor is what you'll get from reading the public field -- only the maker of the class can guarantee that, and they probably won't.  (The name could be converted to uppercase, or looked up for a "nearest match", etc.)

Comment: OK, not planning on verifying the value of the public field, merely want to know that the TF_StringList object is properly instantiated so that I can start using it's insert(const char* ) method to load it with values. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say that depends on what the constructor actually *does*. If we assume it does this:

```
TF_StringList(const char* encoding)
: character_encoding(encoding)
{
}
```

Then your logic holds. But it could do whatever, you don't show a connection between the constructor argument and the instance's member variable.